# ImportError: No module named spitfire.runtime

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new to Google App Engine; I am running Maverick on Mac OS X with python 2.7.  I am trying to run an app that uses the spitfire template system.  I keep getting the below error. I installed spitfire per the instruction on the site (https://code.google.com/p/spitfire/).  I cant seem to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

```
$ dev_appserver.py  .
..........
..........
ImportError: No module named spitfire.runtime
INFO     2013-11-12 21:41:41,246 module.py:608] default: "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2013-11-12 21:41:47,306 wsgi.py:262]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely to work.

It has c code in it - which you can't run on appengine.  Maybe that is an optional component.

Also did you install the code in your appengine project - you should read up on the appengine python sandbox. -- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_The_sandbox

Comment: As an aside did you read the docs about the python runtime, this sort of question comes up every few days, and it seems everyone just dives in without reading anything.  I am not trying to be rude, just curious